# Android SDK getting started

Tags: java, android, sdk

Just trying to get started. I followed the Google instructions and “Download the SDK 
ADT Bundle for Windows”.
I then followed the next step `Install the SDK and Eclipse IDE`

- Unpack the ZIP file (named adt-bundle-.zip) and save it
  to an appropriate location, such as a "Development" directory in your
  home directory.
- Open the adt-bundle-/eclipse/ directory and launch
  eclipse.

When I open the files and try to launch eclipse I get an error:
A JRE or JDK must be available for eclipse to run.
I have reloaded the Java runtime with no success.
Could someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Download JDK from here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

To configure it, follow these steps - 
In the system variables, make a new variable, called it JAVA_HOME, and set the value to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17. After that, edit Path, which is also in the system variables and add : ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin.
If you don't how to do this, follow these steps :
Follow these steps:

Open my Computer.

Go to program files - x86 (if applicable)
Find "java"

Open it and select jre (your number)

Select bin.

Click the bar up the top, You should see something like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin

Paste that into notepad, as you need it soon!

Open the start Menu.

Right click Computer.

Select Properties.

Click "Advanced System Settings"

Click "Environment Variables"

You'll see two Boxes (if not close and follow the instructions again) in the top one Select "New..."

in Variable Name type "PATH" (it must be PATH and not PaTh/Path/pATH.. etc)

In Variable Value, get that thing in Notepad you Pasted in and paste it there.
Press "OK"
Press "Apply"

Answer (score 0):

You Need to install JDK and Java SE Development Kit..

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html